# Type annotations required - why are associated types treated differently?

Tags: rust

In the following program ([play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ec5b43e81b286a638c543e06740aaeda&version=stable&backtrace=0)), the `FooBar` trait provides the `bar` method, but the actual type of the object returned by `bar` seems to be hidden. If I use a type argument instead of an associated type, it works ([play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ba018bc864edc76aa44c153b79f0c662&version=stable&backtrace=0)).

Why are associated types treated differently? Or am I doing it wrong?

```
use std::ops::DerefMut;

pub trait FooBar: Sized {
    type Assoc: Sized + DerefMut<Target=Self>;

    fn foo(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Assoc>;

    fn bar(mut this: Self::Assoc) -> Result<Self::Assoc, Self::Assoc> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test(u32);

impl FooBar for Test {
    type Assoc = Box<Test>;
    fn foo(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Assoc> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tt = Test(20);
    let tt_foo: Box<Test> = tt.foo().unwrap(); // this is ok
    let tt_bar: Box<Test> = FooBar::bar(Box::new(tt)).unwrap(); // but not this
    assert_eq!(tt_bar.0, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method is

```
fn bar(mut this: Self::Assoc) -> Result<Self::Assoc, Self::Assoc>
```

and you try to call it with

```
FooBar::bar(Box::new(tt))
```

how is Rust supposed to know what type `Self` is? `Box::new(tt)` is `Self::Assoc` right, but you can’t get `Self` from that, several types could have the same `Assoc`.

And that’s what `rustc` is complaining about:

> type annotations required

You’d have to annotate what type `Self` is:

```
let tt_bar: Box<Test> = <Test as FooBar>::bar(Box::new(tt)).unwrap();
```

or equivalently:

```
let tt_bar: Box<Test> = Test::bar(Box::new(tt)).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to access the associated type from the trait. You can only access it from a type that implements the trait, such as from `Test`:

```
let tt_bar: Box<Test> = Test::bar(Box::new(tt)).unwrap();
```

`FooBar::Assoc` is not a concrete type, so you cannot use it. When you implemented `FooBar` for `Test`, you gave `Test::Assoc` a concrete type, which is accessible:

```
type Assoc = Box<Test>;
```

In the code with the generic type, a new copy of `FooBar::bar` was created with a concrete type. Because you requested a `Box<Test>`, the new function's signature would be this:

```
fn bar(mut this: Box<Test>) -> Result<Box<Test>, Box<Test>>
```

`Box<Test>` is a concrete type, so it works.